# How do I debug apps using angular+bootstrap (front end) + IIS (backend) from Visual Studio?

Tags: html, angularjs, visual-studio

Specifically, I want to debug the front end without having to stop and restart the server for every change. I am used to doing it when the pages are not served by the development IIS, but I don't know how to do it when they are.
For instance, is you edit an html file in the filesystem it will be updated automatically in the browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For html changes you don't need to restart the website. Run your browser in developer mode (press F12) that will force it to get a fresh page each time. Then press F5 to reload your browser and you will pick up the html changes.

Unfortunately, for jscript changes, you will need to restart the website from Visual Studio press  Ctrl + F5  to restart the website in Visual studio (without debugging visual studio debugging - you can still use browser debugging). At this does not restart the whole of IIS, just the website.

Comment: @OtoLeo - did you get the Angular debugging working?